# Quartz Scheduler Error when Instantiating Job

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to use Quartz 2.1.1 with Spring 3.0.5.

I set up the Scheduler with this line:
`<bean id="scheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean"/>`

I wrote a simple class called `TestJob` that implements the `Job` interface. I am able to successfully set up a job and trigger and schedule it. The problem is that when the job is triggered and quartz tries to instantiate the `TestJob` class, I am getting this error:

```
[scheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] ERROR core.ErrorLogger.schedulerError(2360) | An error occured instantiating job to be
 executed. job= 'TEST_JOB.6d2e7ca2-20cd-4e5f-9f32-1626c7128a5d'
org.quartz.SchedulerException: Problem instantiating class 'com.scheduler.TestJob' -  [See nes
ted exception: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory.newJob(Lorg/quar
tz/spi/TriggerFiredBundle;Lorg/quartz/Scheduler;)Lorg/quartz/Job;]
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.initialize(JobRunShell.java:141)
        at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:381)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory.newJob(Lorg/quartz/s
pi/TriggerFiredBundle;Lorg/quartz/Scheduler;)Lorg/quartz/Job;
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.initialize(JobRunShell.java:134)
        ... 1 more
```

Any ideas on how to get around this issue?

Comment: Could you show the code of your TestJob class? And also the scheduling of your job?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quartz 2 and Spring < 3.1 are incompatible. So you can either update to Spring 3.1 or downgrade to Quartz 1.8. Or you drop the Spring Quartz adapters and use Quartz 2 by hand. I recommend the very first method.

Comment: Had to upgrade to spring 3.1 which was such a pain, but it worked! Thanks!

Comment: If you are upgrading from 3.0 to 3.1 I recommend this guide: http://www.heyitsopower.com/code/upgrading-from-spring-3-0-x-to-spring-3-1-x/

Answer (score 2):

You also can assign the jobFactory to quartz custom job factory "SimpleJobFactory"

Answer (score 1):

I just had a very similar problem that led me here - caused by refactoring a job's package - everything worked till it was deployed to a cluster - quartz jdbc uses tables with job_name column with the old package persisted so it choked with this same error.  Delete the persisted trigger rows, or put it back where it was to resolve.